# Quick question: sufficiently positive divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am referring to line 1-2 of page 472 in Griffiths Harris.

M is a compact complex manifold of dimension 2 that may be embedded in projective space. L is an arbitrary line bundle on M. How can one choose a divisor D on M sufficiently positive so that both the linear series |D| and |L+D| contain smooth, irreducible divisors? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that $|D|$ and $|L+D|$ both contain smooth irreducible divisors, it's enough to arrange that they are both *very ample* linear systems. (Then Bertini's theorem says that the general member of each is smooth and irreducible.)

To ensure they are both very ample, use the following fact: for any line bundle $L$ on $M$, we can write $L=A-B$, with $A$ and $B$ both very ample. Then taking $D=B$ we get $L+D=A$, so both $D$ and $L+D$ are very ample, as required.

Comment: For very ampleness one could also use that given any ample (=positive) line bundle $P$ and any line  bundle $L$, the bundle $L\otimes P^{\otimes k}$ is very ample for $k\gt\gt 0 $ : Griffiths-Harris, page 192, last two lines.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg: indeed, the fact I wrote above (that we can write $L=A-B$ with $A$ and $B$ very ample) is essentially the same as what you say. Your argument is more direct, though.

Comment: Dear @Asal: On the other hand I had never realized that you could write any $L$ as $L=A-B$ with $A,B$ very ample. Thanks for teaching me this.